# Sample Application built with Quickly can't access Web

Tags: application-development, python, quickly

I am running Tutorial application example for Quickly  ( I named App Smallbrowser). This is code from `SmallbrowserWindow.py` :

```
import gettext
from gettext import gettext as _
gettext.textdomain('smallbrowser')

from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit # pylint: disable=E0611
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('smallbrowser')

from smallbrowser_lib import Window
from smallbrowser.AboutSmallbrowserDialog import AboutSmallbrowserDialog
from smallbrowser.PreferencesSmallbrowserDialog import PreferencesSmallbrowserDialog

# See smallbrowser_lib.Window.py for more details about how this class works
class SmallbrowserWindow(Window):
    __gtype_name__ = "SmallbrowserWindow"

    def finish_initializing(self, builder): # pylint: disable=E1002
        """Set up the main window"""
        super(SmallbrowserWindow, self).finish_initializing(builder)

        self.AboutDialog = AboutSmallbrowserDialog
        self.PreferencesDialog = PreferencesSmallbrowserDialog

        # Code for other initialization actions should be added here.

        self.refreshbutton = self.builder.get_object("refreshbutton")
        self.urlentry = self.builder.get_object("urlentry")
        self.scrollwindow = self.builder.get_object("scrollwindow")
        self.webview =  WebKit.WebView()  
        self.scrollwindow.add(self.webview)
        self.webview.show()  

    def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self, widget):
        print "refresh"

    def on_urlentry_activate(self, widget):
        print urlsite     
        urlsite = widget.get_text()

        self.webview.open(urlsite)
```

So when I run Smallbrowser and write desired Url I got this error on WebKit canvas :

> Unable to load page Problem occurred while loading the URL
>   http://www.google.com/ Cannot resolve proxy hostname ()

I don't understand where is my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any errors in the code you have written so i guess the problem lies in the way you have configured your proxy settings for your computer. Go to Network Settings --> Proxy
change the settings to None and try again.

Comment: Well that is main problem. I dont get this error with with Firefox or Chromium? I have fresh installation of Ubuntu from last week and I don't recall setting up any kind of proxy.

Comment: Problem: It was on Automatic in Network Settings Configuration. So I switched to None. It helped.

Answer (score -1):

replace this

```
self.webview.open(urlsite)
```

with this

```
self.webview.open("https://" + urlsite)
```

And it should work.

Comment: If I understand Yours advice correctly I should enforce Https protocol? If Web site natively doesn't support Https I think it wuoldn't work for given example.